# Job Schedule every 1.5hrs or 90 mins

Tags: scheduled-tasks, schedule, job-scheduling

My questions is in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 ->SQL Server Management Studio -> SQL Server Agent -> Jobs

i have created a job which needs to be executed every 1.5hrs or 90mins.

while creating schedule for this job :

New job Schedule -> Daily Frequency -> (I selected)occurs every:

﻿

after focus release from text box time automatically shifted to 60mins

if i select hour(s) and in textbox 1.5

after focus release from text box time automatically shifted to 2 hrs

I need to create a schedule to execute  my job every 1.5 hrs or 90mins.

please help me out for this problem....

Thanks and Regards

Niranjan Bhat

Comment: Please tag this question with the **sql-server** and **sql-server-2008-r2** tags.

Answer (score 0):

If the entry window does not allow you to add fractional hours, then perhaps you could consider adding 2 jobs each executing the same work every 3 hours, but with a 90 minute (1.5 hour) offset.

Put another way:

- Create Job #1 starting at 00:00 (aka. 12:00 AM or midnight) and have it run every 3 hours.
- Create Job #2 starting at 01:30 (aka. 1:30 AM) and have it run every 3 hours.

This way, your two jobs execute as follows:

<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>00:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>01:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>03:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>04:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>06:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>07:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>09:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>10:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>12:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>13:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>15:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>16:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>18:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>19:30</kbd>
<kbd>Job #1</kbd><kbd>21:00</kbd>
<kbd>Job #2</kbd><kbd>22:30</kbd>